# "both this OR that"?

Tags: grammar

I’m a newbie here. I have got some reservations on the usage of the word *both*. To the best of my knowledge, it is followed by *are*. But in a website I just came across this sentence:

> TESOL Canada board exam is required of both native or non-native graduates with or without teaching experience.

Now in this sentence, I personally think the word *both* should be followed by the conjunction *and* in lieu of *or*.
So I’d be grateful if you guys clear this doubt.

[image]

Comment: I also think "both native *or* non-native" should be replaced by "both native **and** non-native". "Both ... or" doesn't sound right in my country (USA). Is it possible this usage is different in Canada? I would be surprised.

Comment: I tend to agree. This would seem to be a piece of bad phrasing (ie a mistake)

Comment: The conjunction doesn't have to follow immediately *both*. (Nor does *both* need to be followed by a conjunction at all: *both of them went home*).But it certainly should not be *both . . .* ***or***. If they actually used *or* when advertising an exam on teaching English, that's a sad commentary.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have it right. "Both x or y" sounds weird to me because it just doesn't make sense logically. Grammatically speaking, it should be

> **Both** native **and** non-native

or

> **Either** native **or** non-native